# Is there a system DMV to monitor the files being loaded?

Tags: azure-synapse, polybase

I'm loading files into Azure DW from blob store using polybase.

I usually use `sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests` and `sys.dm_pdw_sql_requests` to see what any long running processes are doing, but polybase loads have limited information.

Is there a fiew that can show the list of files Polybase has found in the directory and indicate any kind of progress (maybe completed files or rows loaded?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're still adding to the functionality around Polybase monitoring.

Here is a query that will help you to monitor the progress of the current files being loaded. "Current" means that if there are 1,000 files in a data set, and Polybase is processing them 10 at a time, only 10 rows should result from this query at any given time.

```
-- To track bytes and files
SELECT
    r.command,
    s.request_id,
    r.status,
    count(distinct input_name) as nbr_files, 
    sum(s.bytes_processed)/1024/1024/1024 as gb_processed
FROM
    sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests r
    inner join sys.dm_pdw_dms_external_work s
        on r.request_id = s.request_id
GROUP BY
   r.command,
    s.request_id,
    r.status
ORDER BY
    nbr_files desc,
    gb_processed desc;
```

This is an increasingly important topic, and I've created a [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/38453467-polybase-progress-monitoring) task to register user support. Would you mind adding your votes/comments?